# How to include a sub-view in Laravel using a distinct controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, nested-views

There are many threads dealing with sub-views, with many various answers. And I didn't really find a matching answer, although I guess my pattern is quite usual:

A page displays results from a query. The results area can be updated with Ajax by user interactions. Therefore, I have two controllers:

1. `pageDisplay`, which renders the overall view (without the results)
2. `resultsDisplay`, which generates and renders the results using a sub-view

My question deals with the initial display of the results with default settings. How can I call the `resultsDisplay` controller from the `pageDisplay` ?

There are a couple of options I can't (or don't want to) use:

- An initial Ajax request, as this solution is not efficient considering SEO
- Including the sub-view using `@include` as the main view does not know the appropriate variables to send to the sub-view. Those variables are generated by the `resultsDisplay`controller
- Duplicating the code of the `resultsDisplay`controller into the `pageDisplay`controller. This is so ugly and harder to maintain...

Maybe I could call the sub-controller from the main one. But I don't know how to do that since the sub-controller returns a view...

Thanks for your kind assistance!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're after is `nest()` to nest a child view. Here's an example:

```
// Show view and nest sub view passing $foo and $bar to sub view
$foo = 'Some foo data';
$bar = 'Some bar data';
View::make('pageDisplay')->nest('child', 'resultsDisplay', compact('foo', 'bar));
```

Then in your `pageDisplay` view you would simply echo out the nested view:

```
<div id="myChildView">
    {{ $child }}
</div>
```

And in your child view you could use the `$foo` and `$bar` variables you've passed through.

Check out the official docs (under **Passing A Sub-View To A View**) here: http://laravel.com/docs/responses#views